# How do I parallelize in r on windows - example?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

How do I get parallelizaton of code to work in r in Windows? Include a simple example. Posting this self-answered question because this was rather unpleasant to get working. You'll find package parallel does NOT work on its own, but package snow works very well.

Comment: How does the parallel package fail for you? It certainly works for many people, but I think all of the parallel processing packages have more problems on Windows.

Comment: Doesn't work at all on windows but couldn't tell you why. You have to use snow.

Comment: @SteveWeston it fails in the sense that it doesn't allow specification of more than one core for processing. 

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/html/mclapply.html : "It relies on forking and hence is not available on Windows unless `mc.cores = 1`."

Comment: @ijoseph That quote only applies to the "mc" functions (such as mclapply, mcMap, mcmapply, and mcparallel). Functions in parallel that were derived from the snow package (such as parLapply, clusterApply, and clusterApplyLB) don't use `fork` and should execute in parallel on Windows. I've used `parLapply` from both parallel and snow successfully on Windows, but I've also seen lots of ways that both packages can fail, also. That's why I was curious how exactly it failed.

Comment: @SteveWeston ah. Didn't realize `parallel` had those other methods that didn't depend on `fork`. Will be useful, thanks much!

Comment: several tips in blog of R with Parallel Computing from User Perspectives  [here](http://www.parallelr.com/r-with-parallel-computing/).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Posting this because this took me bloody forever to figure out. Here's a simple example of parallelization in r that will let you test if things are working right for you and get you on the right path.

```
library(snow)
z=vector('list',4)
z=1:4
system.time(lapply(z,function(x) Sys.sleep(1)))
cl<-makeCluster(###YOUR NUMBER OF CORES GOES HERE ###,type="SOCK")
system.time(clusterApply(cl, z,function(x) Sys.sleep(1)))
stopCluster(cl)
```

You should also use library doSNOW to register foreach to the snow cluster, this will cause many packages to parallelize automatically. The command to register is `registerDoSNOW(cl)` (with `cl` being the return value from `makeCluster()`) , the command that undoes registration is `registerDoSEQ()`. Don't forget to turn off your clusters.

Comment: Thank you, @Carbon! However, this code does not work in R 4.0.4 and later versions. `makeCluster` just hangs in there without throwing any error. Is there any way to get it worked?

Answer (score 18):

This worked for me, I used package doParallel, required 3 lines of code:

```
# process in parallel
library(doParallel) 
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores(), type='PSOCK')
registerDoParallel(cl)

# turn parallel processing off and run sequentially again:
registerDoSEQ()
```

Calculation of a random forest decreased from 180 secs to 120 secs (on a Windows computer with 4 cores).

Comment: what is the difference in using `type='PSOCK'` instead of `type = 'SOCK'` ?

Answer (score 5):

Based on the information [here](http://www.uio.no/english/services/it/research/hpc/courses/r/2013-04_parallel_r.pdf) I was able to convert the following code into a parallelised version that worked under R Studio on Windows 7.

Original code:

```
#
# Basic elbow plot function
#
wssplot <- function(data, nc=20, seed=1234){
    wss <- (nrow(data)-1)*sum(apply(data,2,var))
    for (i in 2:nc){
        set.seed(seed)
        wss[i] <- sum(kmeans(data, centers=i, iter.max=30)$withinss)}
    plot(1:nc, wss, type="b", xlab="Number of clusters", 
       ylab="Within groups sum of squares")
}
```

Parallelised code:

```
library("parallel")

workerFunc <- function(nc) {
  set.seed(1234)
  return(sum(kmeans(my_data_frame, centers=nc, iter.max=30)$withinss)) }

num_cores <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(num_cores)
clusterExport(cl, varlist=c("my_data_frame")) 
values <- 1:20 # this represents the "nc" variable in the wssplot function
system.time(
  result <- parLapply(cl, values, workerFunc) )  # paralel execution, with time wrapper
stopCluster(cl)
plot(values, unlist(result), type="b", xlab="Number of clusters", ylab="Within groups sum of squares")
```

Not suggesting it's perfect or even best, just a beginner demonstrating that parallel does seem to work under Windows. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

I think these libraries will help you:

```
foreach (facilitates executing the loop in parallel)
doSNOW (I think you already use it)
doMC (multicore functionality of the parallel package)
```

May these article also help you

http://vikparuchuri.com/blog/parallel-r-loops-for-windows-and-linux/

http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/parallel-computing-r-windows-using-dosnow-foreach/

Comment: The doMC package depends on the mclapply function to execute tasks, so it can't execute in parallel on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

I'm posting a cross-platform answer here because all the other answers I found were over-complicated for what I needed to accomplish. I'm using an example where I'm reading in all sheets of an excel workbook.

```
# read in the spreadsheet 
parallel_read <- function(file){

    # detect available cores and use 70%
    numCores  = round(parallel::detectCores() * .70)

    # check if os is windows and use parLapply
    if(.Platform$OS.type == "windows") {

        cl <- makePSOCKcluster(numCores)
        parLapply(cl, file, readxl::read_excel)
        stopCluster(cl)

        return(dfs)

    # if not Windows use mclapply
    } else {

        dfs <-parallel::mclapply(excel_sheets(file), 
                         readxl::read_excel, 
                         path = file,
                         mc.cores=numCores)

        return(dfs)

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For what it is worth. I was running into the same problem but couldn't get any of these to work. I eventually learned that Rstudio has a 'jobs' pane and can run models in the background each on it's own core. so what I did was divy-up my model into 10 segments (it was iterative over 100 vectors so 10 scripts of 10 vectors each) and ran each as a separate job. that way when one finished I could use the output from it immediately and I could keep working on my script without waiting for each model to finish. here is the link all about using jobs https://blog.rstudio.com/2019/03/14/rstudio-1-2-jobs/