# Speeding up or replacing nested loop in R

Tags: r, performance, loops

I was trying to use dynamic time series warping with time series of different length with the idea in mind of comparing all of them to identify different clusters. For that I am using the dtw library. But the problem I´ve found is more high level. I am trying to create a distance matrix with the distance of each series respecting the others, and for indexing it the only way I come with is a long nested loop which is really slow.By the way, hell is a list that contains all the time series. I`d like to have some guidance on the best approach for speeding up this operation.

```
for (j in 1:10){
    for(i in 1:10){
        alig =  dtw(hell[[i]],hell[[j]],open.end=T,open.begin=T,step=asymmetric,keep=T)  
        m[i,j] = (alig$distance) 
   }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps, the function `outer` could be useful in this case

Comment: You are almost certainly going to have to put this in C/C++ to speed it up unless you can get a vectorized version of dtw. You can check out this post by the RCPP guys for some very straightforward instructions for doing a distance matrix in R using RCPP.http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/parallel-distance-matrix/

Comment: Also, you can get some simple parallelism by using mclapply or a parallel foreach if you are on a machine with more than 1 core.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answers. @MaratTalipov I am taking a look at outer, seems very interesting, however is failing in applying complex functions, I will check with more detail.

Comment: @jimmyb The C thing is something I am willing to do as a last resource, regarding to mclapply, I thought it only worked on Unix devices.

Comment: If you give a sample input and output, I'd be happy to help you with `outer`

Comment: @comendeiro check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23926334/how-do-i-parallelize-in-r-on-windows-example