# Parallelizing Training Multiple Networks in R (with Keras)

Tags: r, keras, parallel-processing, deep-learning

I want to train n different neural networks in R in *parallel*, how can I do this?  I'm fairly new to parallelization so I find this a bit difficult.

Here is my code for 1 network (so far):

```
model<-keras_model_sequential()
# Define bulk of the network
model %>% layer_dense(units=Height,activation = "relu",input_shape = 1)


for(i in 1:Depth){
  model %>% layer_dense(units=Height,activation = "relu",input_shape = 1) 
}

# Readout Layer (ffNN)
model %>% layer_dense(units=1)

# Compile (ffNN)
model %>% keras::compile(loss="mse",
                         optimizer="adam",
                         metrics="mse")


## Report Model (Summary)
model %>% summary()

# Fit ffNN
fit.ffNN.start<-Sys.time()
fittedmodel<- model %>%
  keras::fit(train_data,
             trainingtarget,
             epochs=epochs,
             batch_size=(round(min(1,abs(Batch.size.percent))*nrow(train_data),digits = 0)), # Computes batch-size as a percentage of total data-size
  )
fit.ffNN.end<-Sys.time()
```

Comment: and you couldn't find anything on the net how to parallelize in R? `mclapply`, `lapply, `parLapply` is the way to go and indeed be used for the `fit` method then

Comment: I'm a bit new to all, this so I do thing this confusing.  Sorry, if this is a basic question.

Comment: no worries, but I think tutorials for parallelizing in R in general would be the best for you, e.g. https://nceas.github.io/oss-lessons/parallel-computing-in-r/parallel-computing-in-r.html, etc.

Comment: also, did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23926334/how-do-i-parallelize-in-r-on-windows-example ?

Comment: So I should wrap this into a function (with empty input) and then perform mcapply?

Comment: Before you go down the path of trying to parallelize around 'keras', make sure to check whether 'keras' already do parallelization internally (e.g. multi-threading) or not.  If it does, then there's little to gain to parallelize on top of it (unless you parallelize across multiple machines).