# How to make keras utilize all available CPU capacity when training?

Tags: r, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, cpu

I am trying to implement a bunch of different neural networks for a regression problem. When I train a single model I see that my computer doesn't utilize all the available CPU, which I guess would be preferable to make the training faster.

Ultimately I want to specify multiple models (around 4), that can be trained simultaneously, but to begin with I just want to utilize all CPU when training a single model. The screenshot below shows how my CPU is used when i train a model:

[CPU utilization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KU3uh.png)

In the code below I tried setting `use_multiprocessing = TRUE`, which I thought could help, but I get the error that the argument is not used.

```
library(keras)

epoch <- 50

lr <- 0.1

decay <- lr / epoch

# initialize model

fit_NN4 <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
  layer_flatten(input_shape = training %>% select(-date, -mktcap, -permno, -ret.adj) %>% ncol()) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 64, activation = "relu") %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 32, activation = "relu") %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 16, activation = "relu") %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 8, activation = "relu") %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 1)

# compile

fit_NN4 %>% compile(
  loss = "mse", # loss objective function
  #optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(), 
  optimizer = optimizer_sgd(lr = lr, decay = decay),
  metrics = c("mean_absolute_error")
)

# train the model

fit_NN4 %>% 
  fit(
    
    # Training data
    
    x = training %>% select(-date, -mktcap, -permno, -ret.adj) %>% as.matrix(), 
    y = training %>% pull(ret.adj) %>% as.matrix(),
    
    epoch = epoch,
    
    # Validation data
    
    validation_data = 
      list(validation %>% select(-date, -mktcap, -permno, -ret.adj) %>% as.matrix(), 
            validation %>% pull(ret.adj) %>% as.matrix()),
    
    # Callbacks
    
    callbacks = list(
      callback_early_stopping(monitor = "val_loss", # early stop objective
                              mode = "min",         # minimize objective
                              verbose = 1,          # Return epoch at stop
                              patience = 4         # wait for 4 epochs to stop relative to min
                              use_multiprocessing = TRUE
                              )) # Use all CPU capacity       
    )
```

Comment: I get `Error: object 'training' not found`

Comment: Yes, i didnt upload the whole dataset since its huge. So the code snippet is just the model architecture, and does not include the data.

Comment: did you see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60111469/parallelizing-training-multiple-networks-in-r-with-keras

Comment: It further links to this which seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23926334/how-do-i-parallelize-in-r-on-windows-example