# Multiple Core Usage/Parallelize Map Function for an RQA

Tags: r, parallel-processing, recurrence, map-function, cpu-cores

I am currently trying to run a windowed CRQA in R using heart and respiration waveform signals. I have to run 94 windowed CRQA, where each signal has 20000 - 50000 data points. Hence the computational load is relatively high and takes forever. Therefore I am trying to get R to increase the memory size and use multiple cores. Both this does not seem to work with the folllowing code:

```
library(parallel)
library(doParallel) 
library(crqa)
gc()
# Set Memory Size (PC has 16000 RAM)
memory.limit(size = 17000)
memory.size(max=TRUE)

numCores <- detectCores() # core = 11

# Simulate Example Data
HR1 = c(arima.sim(list(order=c(1,0,2),ar=-0.6,ma=c(0.5,-0.7)),sd=sqrt(0.5),n=40000))
HR2 = c(arima.sim(list(order=c(1,0,2),ar=-0.7,ma=c(0.5,-0.7)),sd=sqrt(0.5),n=20000))
HR3 = c(arima.sim(list(order=c(1,0,2),ar=-0.8,ma=c(0.5,-0.7)),sd=sqrt(0.5),n=30000))

RR1 = c(arima.sim(list(order=c(1,0,2),ar=-0.4,ma=c(0.5,-0.7)),sd=sqrt(0.5),n=40000))
RR2 = c(arima.sim(list(order=c(1,0,2),ar=-0.3,ma=c(0.5,-0.7)),sd=sqrt(0.5),n=20000))
RR3 = c(arima.sim(list(order=c(1,0,2),ar=-0.2,ma=c(0.5,-0.7)),sd=sqrt(0.5),n=30000))

HR_list = list(HR1, HR2, HR3)
RR_list = list(RR1, RR2, RR3)

# Create Cluster
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores(), type='PSOCK')
registerDoParallel(cl)

# Run the Windowed CRQA
start_time <- Sys.time()
WCRQA_list = Map(function(x, y)
  wincrqa(ts1 = x, ts2 = y, windowstep = 1000, windowsize = 2000,
          radius = .2, delay = 4, embed = 2, rescale = 0, normalize = 0,
          mindiagline = 2, minvertline = 2, tw = 0, whiteline = F,
          side = "both", method = "crqa", metric = "euclidean", datatype = "continuous"),
  HR_list, RR_list)
end_time <- Sys.time()
end_time - start_time

registerDoSEQ()
```

Why does R not reclaim the memory size and cores it actually could? Checked it in the task manager and both does not seem to work.
How could I solve this problem to actually run this code on my actual data set?

I am open to any help.

Best,
Johnson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `clusterMap()` or another function from the `parallel` package rather than `base::Map`.

Look those options up with: `?parallel::clusterMap`.

You are also currently mixing things up by introducing `registerDoParallel(cl)`, which is from the `foreach` package. That would require you to then use `foreach()` and its helper `%dopar%`. If you do not use `foreach()` then you do not need `registerDoParallel(cl)`.

The relevant part of your code would look something like this with `clusterMap()`. I've tidied it a bit but I can't test it on my machine.

```
my_wincrqa <-function(x, y) {

crqa::wincrqa(ts1 = x, ts2 = y, windowstep = 1000, windowsize = 2000,
          radius = .2, delay = 4, embed = 2, rescale = 0, normalize = 0,
          mindiagline = 2, minvertline = 2, tw = 0, whiteline = F,
          side = "both", method = "crqa", metric = "euclidean", datatype = "continuous")

}

WCRQA_list = clusterMap(cl, my_wincrqa, HR_list, RR_list)
```

Normally, it'd be best to test things first in a smaller scale. That's probably even more important for parallel computing and even more so considering how painful it is for parallel computing to work on R for Windows. Have a look at [this self-answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23926334/how-do-i-parallelize-in-r-on-windows-example) to set up a quick test. `snow` is now essentially `parallel` AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have an example of how to exactly use the clusterMap() function in my example? From the description of the function this not obvious on how to adapt my code.

Comment: I ran the following code: `my_wincrqa = function(x, y) {
  wincrqa(ts1 = x, ts2 = y, windowstep = 1000, windowsize = 2000,
          radius = .2, delay = 4, embed = 2, rescale = 0, normalize = 0,
          mindiagline = 2, minvertline = 2, tw = 0, whiteline = F,
          side = "both", method = "crqa", metric = "euclidean", datatype = "continuous")
}
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores(), type = "PSOCK")
registerDoParallel(cl)
start_time <- Sys.time()
WCRQA_list = clusterMap(cl, my_wincrqa, HR_list, RR_list)
end_time <- Sys.time()
end_time - start_time
registerDoSEQ()` I

Comment: And then I got this error: `Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  2 nodes produced errors; first error: function "wincrqa" not found`

Comment: I see, the parallel cores will be empty. Try referring to the function explicitly with: `crqa::wincrqa`. I've changed the answer, too.

Comment: great! That solved the problem. Thanks a lot !!!! :)

Comment: no worries, you can mark the question as answered by clicking on the tick sign next to it