# "Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 2 nodes produced errors; first error: could not find function "wincrqa"

Tags: r, error-handling, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, parallel-foreach

I am currently trying to run a parallelized RQA with the following code.

```
library(snow)
library(doSNOW)
library(crqa)
    my_wincrqa = function(x, y){
      wincrqa(x, y, windowstep = 1000, windowsize = 2000,
              radius = .2, delay = 4, embed = 2, rescale = 0, normalize = 0,
              mindiagline = 2, minvertline = 2, tw = 0, whiteline = F,
              side = "both", method = "crqa", metric = "euclidean", datatype = "continuous")
    }
cl<-makeCluster(11,type="SOCK")
start_time <- Sys.time()
WCRQA_list = clusterMap(cl, my_wincrqa, HR_list, RR_list)
end_time <- Sys.time()
end_time - start_time
```

Unfortunately, I get this: "

> Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :  2 nodes produced errors; first
> error: could not find function "wincrqa"

I know there is probably sum error in setting up the parallel processing, but I am not able to resolve it. I also tried a similar thing using the parallel() package.

I am happy for any help!

Best,
Johnson

Comment: Did you load `crqa` package ? `library(crqa)`

Comment: yes I did. It seems to be related to the parallel processing part.

Comment: johnson24, see my reply in your original question. Each node needs to have an idea of where the function comes from.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Core Usage/Parallelize Map Function for an RQA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67916760/multiple-core-usage-parallelize-map-function-for-an-rqa)

Comment: Side comment: Instead of using "legacy" packages **snow** and **doSNOW**, I recommend using **parallel** (comes with R since 2011) and **doParallel** instead. The **parallel** package, which has the same author have seen lots of improvements since, whereas **snow** is just kept on life support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you’ve loaded and attached the ‘crqa’ package in your main execution environment, but the cluster nodes are running code in separate, isolated R sessions — they don’t see the same loaded packages or global variables!

The easiest solution is to replace use of `wincrqa` with a fully qualified name, i.e. to use `crqa::wincrqa` inside your function.

Alternatively, it is possible to attach the ‘crqa’ package on all cluster nodes prior to executing the function:

```
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(crqa))
WCRQA_list = clusterMap(cl, my_wincrqa, HR_list, RR_list)
```